# Using ConcatenatingMediaSource for ExoPlayer in Android

Tags: playlist, exoplayer2.x

I was reading the official docs about making a playlist using `ConcatenatingMediaSource` for my `ExoPlayer` in Android. [At this link](https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html) they provide the following example:

```
MediaSource firstSource =
    new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(firstVideoUri);
MediaSource secondSource =
    new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(secondVideoUri);
// Plays the first video, then the second video.
ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource =
    new ConcatenatingMediaSource(firstSource, secondSource);
```

In that example, they have two URIs and therefore two `MediaSource` objects will be created and then concatenated with each other.

I get this but now my question: When I have let's say 1000 URIs (each representing a track of my playlist), then do I need to create 1000 `MediaSource` objects ? What if I have more than 1000, let's 10000 or maybe more?
I can guess that this would not be memory efficient, right ?

So, what would be the right way to handle such a case (with more than 2 `MediaSource` objects) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this, let's assume the songs list contain 1000 or more than that, it will handle that and as result, you will get concatenatingMediaSource

```
val concatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()
        songs.forEach { song ->
            val mediaItem:MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(song.getString(METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_URI).toUri())
            val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(mediaItem)
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource)
        }
```